# Partitioning List Into Sublists of Length 2 With The Pairing Being Random

Tags: list-manipulation, random, partitions

I've done a bit of Googling with hopes of finding an answer, but to no avail. I'm looking for a way that I can have Mathematica take the elements of a list, say `{a,b,c,d}`, and partition the elements into lists of length 2 but allowing the grouping of these elements to be *random*. The `Partition` function nearly produces the desired results, but groups the elements in `{a,b,c,d}` in the order they appear (i.e. the result is `{{a,b},{c,d}}`) when I would like a random pairing such as `{{a,d},{c,b}}`.

Is there some way of utilizing the `Partition` function so that it allows me achieve this? Or there perhaps another built-in function or combination of built-in functions that do this?

Thank you all so very much.

Comment: `Partition[RandomSample[(* stuff *)], (* stuff *)]` ought to work…

Comment: I'm having difficulty applying this to a more sophisticated set that I'm using. It worked well when I applied this to `{a,b,c,d}`, but when using this with the list I'm working with that is of length 19, it gives me the error "RandomSample cannot generate a random sample of length 2 which is greater than the length of the sample set".

UPDATE: I got it to work! Thank you!

Comment: "I got it to work!" - may I recommend writing an answer to your question to show how you made it work? ;)

Comment: It was a simple syntax error on my part. I called the list I was working with `ConvertedList` and initially used the following input `Partition[RandomSample[{ConvertedList}],5],2]` which resulted in an error because the curly brackets weren't necessary. Writing `Partition[RandomSample[ConvertedList],5],2]` fixed the issue.

Comment: May I ask if there is a way to get all the possible ways of pairing? (instead of just a random pairng)

Answer (score 2):

While David G. Stork's solution works it is not efficient. You are generating all possible tuples and then selecting them randomly. Try this with a list of 19 elements in tuples of 10 and you will be waiting forever.

This solution should work just fine with lists of any length

```
list = {a, b, c, d};
Partition[
    RandomSample[list]
 , 2]

{{c, d}, {b, a}}
```

@Qwerty to produce a specific number of pairs, you should try something like this:

```
list = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g};
numberOfPairs = 3;
Partition[
    RandomSample[list, numberOfPairs*2]
 , 2]

{{f, a}, {g, c}, {e, d}}
```

Note that Length@list must be greater or equal to 2*numberOfPairs

Comment: If you do just `RandomSample[list]`, you will only get one out of the many permutations of `list`.

Comment: But you said that you just want one random pairing. This approach gives give you a random pairing each time.

Comment: So does my suggestion; try it out.

Comment: oh.... you mean to get rid of  "Length@list" right? It does work. Im changing the answer based on that.

Comment: Exactly. $\phantom{}$

Comment: Ah, this works as well! Thank you for the input!

Answer (score 0):

```
RandomSample[Tuples[{a, b, c, d}, 2]]
```

If you want a fixed number of pairs (say 5):

```
Take[RandomSample[Tuples[{a, b, c, d}, 2]], 5]
```

Comment: This works quiet well! Is there a way of forcing it to produce a specific number of pairs?

Answer (score 0):

Could this work for your problem?

```
A = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g}
list = Union[Flatten[Map[Partition[#, 2] &, Permutations[A]], 1]]
Extract[list, RandomInteger[{1, Length[list]}]]
```

Change the predicate in the Partition function for different lengths.

```
f[_] := Extract[list, RandomInteger[{1, Length[list]}]]
Array[f, 10]
```

will generate 10 subsets for (pseudo)random pairs.